# Convert date format in export filename

Tags: date, split, filenames

I am trying to split an export file by date and format the date to yyyyMMdd from yyyy-mm-dd. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
@Override
public String getFilename(String filenamePattern, Long jobId, Map<String, String> rowData) {
    String dateId = rowData.get("field::sales:date");
    return MessageFormat.format("Sales_Report.csv", DateUtil.formatFromStandardTo(dateId,"yyyyMMdd"), String.valueOf(jobId));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I’m not sure I get your context. However, conversion from yyyy-MM-dd to yyyyMMdd format is straightforward:

```
    String dateId = "2021-07-08";
    
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateId);
    String formattedDate = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);

    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output:

> 20210708

I am exploiting that both of your formats are ISO 8601. `LocalDate` parses the yyyy-MM-dd ISO 8601 variant as its default, that is, without us specifying a formatter. And a formatter for the compacter yyyyMMdd variant is built as `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)